# Azure: client principal name is missing with docker compose

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to get the X-Ms-Client-Principal-Name value from the request header but it doesn't come anymore after I change the container settings from Single Container to Docker Compose.
Any idea why is this happening?

This is the docker-compose file that I'm using:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: webimage:v1.0.0
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
```

Both images are correctly downloaded from the repository and launched

Comment: You need to share the docker-compose file you use.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've just added the docker-compose config

Comment: Any more logs? It seems no problem with the docker-compose.

Comment: I think, based on this answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/11606/view.html that AAD is no yet implemented for Docker compose

Comment: Does it need to authenticate?

Comment: Yes, my client is using AAD to authenticate and they want to keep it

Comment: Well, if you solve the question, please add an answer to display it.